# Defining vector in Verilog

Tags: verilog

Given the following code:

```
module add16 (input [15:0] a,b, output[15:0] sum, output court);
```

Are both `input a` and `input b` 16 bits long, or is only `input a` 16 bits long?

Comment: After digging deep into Verilog, I mean seeing more Verilog examples. I think this question is obvious, both `input a` and `input b` are 16 bits. However, is this just a coding convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is:

```
<direction> <type> [<packed size] list,of,var,names
```

The same principle applies to all variables.

So in your example as `b` has no direction/type/size definitions, it will take the same definitions as the port that came before it, `a`, hence both should be the same size and direction.

Personally I avoid this syntax an prefer to specify each ports direction, type and size individually. I find it clearer and avoids any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Until you specify a direction, a parameter "inherits" its size and direction from the previous one.

Re-write the module definition:

```
module add16 (
   input [15:0] a, b,
   output [15:0] sum,
   output carryout
);
```

Should be clearer now.

Here `b` "inherits" its direction and size from `a`.

If you wrote `output [15:0] sum, carryout` the `carryout` would be 16-bit long. But defining another direction with `output` allowed you to specify a size, 1-bit in this case.

Comment: Thanks! So, in this example, the `output` is the direction and the `type` is omitted.

Comment: @mendax1234 the `output` is direction, yes. For `type`, you normally don't have to specify a type for module inputs i.e. it's already in "bits" and you specify the size only. So the syntax is `dir [MSB:LSB] var_name`.

Comment: @mendax1234 when a direction is given, type is assumed to be `wire`. For outputs you can also have `output reg`.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Okok. So, what's the difference between `output reg` and `output wire`? I know that if I want to assign the output value in an always block, it needs to be a reg and it can't be the wire. Are there any other differences?

Comment: @mendax1234 That's the only difference, the reg type can be assigned in a procedural block.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Thanks. I think you are an expert at EE, so, may I ask an unrelated question here :lol:? That's can you recommend a book to introduce verilog for beginners? Now I take verilog because I need to use it to do some work on FPGA, like implementing a 7-segment decode. However, I find that it is important to dig deeper into Verilog, like learning other programming languages, like C. So, can you give me some recommendations? Thanks! Edited: I know that there are many recommendations online, and because of that, I don't know which one to choose. :lol: